# Create range/buckets as per two columns

Tags: r

I have searched hard to find solution on this but I only find interval and frequency distribution solutions.

I have a big dataset with more 100,000 rows and 2 columns and showing a sample of this below.

This dataset(nm) have two columns as mentioned below:

```
nm
predict actual
502.31  215.66
369.43  143.48
108.43  0.00
273.28  87.87
108.43  0.00
268.19  86.00
108.43  0.00
108.43  0.00
108.43  0.00
268.19  86.82
108.43  0.00
108.43  5.00
268.19  88.00
108.43  5.00
```

Now I want to have new dataset(kl) in which following output is needed:

```
kl
pred1   actual_range
108.43  0 - 5
502.31  215.66
268.19  86 - 88
273.28  87.87
```

Pred_1 should have all unique values of predict and Actual_range should have range/buckets of that particular predict value as per actual column.

How can I create this for big dataset.

If my question is still not clear then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by operation.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(nm)`), grouped by 'predict', get the `range` of 'actual', `paste` the `unique` elements together

```
library(data.table)
setDT(nm)[, .(actual_range = paste(unique(range(actual)), collapse='-')), predict]
```

Comment: And a base R analog, `aggregate(cbind("actual_range"=actual) ~ predict, data=df, FUN=function(x) paste(unique(range(x)), collapse="-"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using base-R :

```
DF <- read.csv(text=
"predict,actual
502.31,215.66
369.43,143.48
108.43,0.00
273.28,87.87
108.43,0.00
268.19,86.00
108.43,0.00
108.43,0.00
108.43,0.00
268.19,86.82
108.43,0.00
108.43,5.00
268.19,88.00
108.43,5.00")


res <-aggregate(actual~predict,
                data=DF,
                FUN=function(x){  
                  minV <- min(x)
                  maxV <- max(x)
                  if(minV != maxV)
                    return(paste0(minV,'-',maxV))
                  return(minV)
                })

> res
  predict actual
1  108.43    0-5
2  268.19  86-88
3  273.28  87.87
4  369.43 143.48
5  502.31 215.66
```